# Executing unittests in a python egg after deployment

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I have a Python egg deployed to an edge node of our Hadoop cluster, as we have some integration tests that can only be run in the cluster.

I'd like to add a step in our testing process where we run our unit tests, and then the integration tests if the unit tests pass. My issue is that we only deploy a python egg, and though it contains all of our app's code, I don't know how to get to the tests with nose.

Ideally I'd like to be able to call it from a Python script outside the egg.

Something like

```
 nose.run(argv=['Example.egg', 'example-module'])
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've answered my own question. The egg can be added to the PYTHONPATH and accessed as if it were expanded.

```
export PYTHONPATH='/path/to/egg/Example.egg'

nosetests example-module
```